# Migrating from Centos7 to Rocky9, javafx app now just renders a blank window

Tags: javafx

everybody:

Not a java developer here.

Some time back, a student here at the office wrote a small java/javafx authentication app; the student is long gone, and the app has been working fine.

Now, IT is migrating Linux from Centos7 to Rocky9.

The java/javafx app now just renders a blank window when executed in Rocky9...I am looking for a solution to this issue.

Previously, we run into a similar issue with a Python application and a google search yielded something about passing "--no-sandbox" to the program.

I guess it has something to do with the fact that these programs are browser based?

Is there already a known solution to this issue for the javafx case?

I am hoping the solution is as simple as for the Python case.

Thanks.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are likely too many things that could potentially go wrong when attempting such a migration that it is unlikely you will receive concrete help here.

Comment: The migration is going fine, but I mentioned it so that it is clear which OS I am working on; but do not mind that much, let's focus on HOW to request "NO SANDBOX" when rendering an app that uses javafx / webengine kind of stuff.

Comment: `--no-sandbox` is not a JavaFX option. A search shows up a [`--no-sandbox` option for Chromium](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68832/what-does-the-chromium-option-no-sandbox-mean). JavaFX does not use Chromium, internally it uses a branch of WebKit as part of its WebEngine implementation. Chromium related documentation and switches do not apply to JavaFX. The Chromium sandbox is related to the Chrome specific security architecture, which [is not present in WebKit](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/7915). You can't request "NO SANDBOX" as there is none already.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got around to continuing some work on this issue...I did two things, thing #1 and thing #2, and the issue went away; thus, I don't even know if I needed thing #1  ;-)

First, I upgraded the version of javafx that was being used
Second, instead of using the system default java 11, I used java 17

Now, the app with the same sources is back working just fine.